# Is launching a batch file from a UWP app possible?

Tags: c#, batch-file, uwp

I've seen some conflicting answers here and on the Microsoft forums about this, is it possible to launch a batch file from a UWP application?

I'm trying the C# example posted here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync#Windows_System_Launcher_LaunchUriAsync_Windows_Foundation_Uri_

The string I'm passing in is @"C:\Program Files\ExampleApp\test.bat", but am having no luck - also not sure how to debug this function LaunchUriAsync(Uri) as it is an Microsoft API function call

Answer (score 2):

Not from a normal UWP, and never on a Windows 10 desktop in "S" Mode, but you can do it if you build a Full Trust (aka Desktop Bridge) app if you don't need to run on "S" Mode machines.

You can run processes that are included in your package but they will still run in the context of your security container.

Comment: I think this might be what I have here, what is the solution? It is a side-loaded application and I do have existing code that successfully launches a .exe using the code I posted in the main post.

Comment: The .exe is being referenced with a custom URI scheme "appname:"

Comment: If you already have an application registered to handle that scheme then it should just work.